# Copiar archivos de un servidor a una pc Xampp

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, xampp

Tengo un carusel de imagenes y videos que salen desde una petición en JQuery y estan alojadas en un servidor de xXmpp compartido en la LAN

Mi problema es cuando el enlace esta muy lejos se pierde el video y me preguntaba si ahi alguna forma de copiar los archivos que estan en el servidor a las pc donde se estan usando.

Lo habia pensado de esta forma:

```
 \File::copy('http://localhost/turnomatic/public/comercial/'.$c->ruta, '/Users/teknol/Desktop/comerciales'.$c->ruta );
```

Haciendo pruebas en servidor local funciona pero pasandolo al servidor y poniendo la ip de donde esta el server:

```
\File::copy('http://192.168.100.111:8080/turnomatic/public/comercial/'.$c->ruta, '/Users/teknol/Desktop/comerciales'.$c->ruta );
```

Me arroja este error:

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory ErrorException in
>   Filesystem.php line 158:
>   copy(/Users/teknol/Desktop/comerciales/AguaLogo.png): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory

Gracias por su atención.

Comment: Puede ser permisos de escritura. Que sistema operativo usas? En dado caso si tienes todos los permisos, puede que tu ruta no este bien hecha.

Comment: La pc del cliente es windows 10 y el servidor corre en windows server 2008
@cig

Comment: Utiliza `move_uploaded_file(...)` y asegúrate que tu ruta este correcta. :D

Comment: pero move_upload_file() ocupan un input? yo necesito que se bajen automaticamente a la pc de una manera que sea casi invisible cuando hace la peticion por jquery con ajax